# My regular expression is matching but while doing with java it is not matching

Tags: java, regex

My regular expression:

```
VARCHAR2+\(+[0-9]+\)
```

is matching with `VARCHAR2(50)` but while executing this expression with java patterns class matcher it is not matching.

Comment: Is it matching or not? When is it matching?

Comment: The syntax you're using in your question is not Java regex syntax. See the javadoc for `Pattern` class.

Comment: I have checked above expression in tutorial.that regular expression is correct and when i am doing it with java.it is not getting. actually i want to replace it with string.replacement is not done.

Comment: I guess you want `String ptrn = "VARCHAR\\d+\\(([0-9]+)\\)"`.

Comment: What is your java code to check this regexp? BTW you probably don't need the 2 first `+`’s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println("VARCHAR2(50)".matches("VARCHAR2+\\(+[0-9]+\\)"));
result: true
```

You need to make it `\\`

Comment: ya it may be right but it is not replacing with String i have placed it in property file as   VARCHAR2+\\(+[0-9]+\\)=String. By using patterns it should replace VARCHAR2(50) with String but it is not getting replaced while other key values in properties file are succesfully getting modifying in my file.

Comment: Do you use replace or replaceAll? Because replace is not regex based. Try this one:
"VARCHAR2(50)".replaceAll("VARCHAR2+\\\(+[0-9]+\\\)","replaced");

Comment: ya i  used replaceAll

Comment: well I tested the code above and it replaces the string properly. Maybe if you give more information about your problem or the whole code it will be easier to locate the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with escaping special characters. Java uses esteblished regular expression syntax and unfortunately both Java and regular expressions use the same syntax.

Thus, the Java string literal `"VARCHAR2+\(+[0-9]+\)"` denotes the sequence of characters `VARCHAR2+(+[0-9]+)`. In this regular expression the parantheses denote grouping, and therefore the regular expression does not match your input string.

To solve this, you need escape special characters twice. The Java string literal `"VARCHAR2+\\(+[0-9]+\\)"` denotes the string `VARCHAR2+\(+[0-9]+\)`, and here the parantheses are escaped, so this regular expression matches your input.